# Conditional probability and indeterminate form

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Consider a finite and discrete setup.
It is well known that, given two events $A$ and $B$, the probability of $A$ knowing $B$ is:

$$P(A | B) = \frac{P(A \wedge B)}{P(B)}.$$

Suppose now that $B$ is impossible, i.e. $P(B) = 0$. Similarly, $P(A \wedge B) = 0$. Moreover, suppose that $A \neq B$. Therefore, I would get an indeterminate form:

$$P(A | B) = \frac{0}{0}.$$

Anyway, it seems more plausible to me that:

$$P(A | B) = \begin{cases}
\displaystyle\frac{P (A \wedge B)}{P(B)} & \text{if}~P(B) > 0\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.$$

Is this formalism right?

Comment: No, here is an example: Let $B$ be the event that if you choose a random natural number, you choose the number 1. It is well known that $P(B) = 0$. But, $P(B|B) = 1$.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe Good point. What does it happen if we work with finite sets only?

Comment: @InterstellarProbe. Moreover, what if we add the constraint that $A \neq B$?

Comment: Discrete probabilities are usually easier than continuous ones. I would imagine that given those two constraints, you would be correct. It may even be that $P(B|B)$ is undefined if $P(B)=0$ for probabilities of events dealing with finite sets.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe I've edited my question according to your comments. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've thought more about it. When the probabilities are discrete, does it make sense to have a probability of the form $P(A|B)$ when $P(B)=0$? The idea of the former probability is that you are saying that no matter how impossible $B$ happens to be, assume it happened. Now that the impossible occurred, what is the probability of $A$ occuring? This may be an undefined situation.